# Store.select bug?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ngrx

Store.select should get a string that tell him what property of the store I want to observe but the problem is that he doesn't have those properties.
Insead he have the reducer function as a property that expose the state properties.

By https://github.com/ngrx/store its easy to notice that something is wrong.

Thier code:

```
counter: Observable<number>;
constructor(public store: Store<AppState>){
     this.counter = store.select('counter');
}
```

My code:

```
export interface AppState{
  connectedAccountId:number;
}
@Injectable()
export class ConnectedAccountService {
  public connectedAccountId$:Observable<number>;
  constructor(private _store:Store<AppState>,private _accountService:AccountService)
  {
    this.connectedAccountId$ = this._store
      .select(state=>
      {
        console.log(state);
        let id:number=state.connectedAccountId; //x=undefined because state doesn't have 'connectedAccountId' property.
        return state.connectedAccountReducer.connectedAccountId; //this line is working!
        // Error:(35, 22) TS2339: Property 'connectedAccountReducer'
        // does not exist on type 'AppState'.
      });

    this.connectedAccountId$ = this._store.select("connectedAccountId");
    // Error:(37, 5) TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not
    // assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.
    // Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  }
```

the following code will work and do what it needs to do with a big error:

```
this.connectedAccountId$ = this._store
      .select(state=>
      {
        return state.connectedAccountReducer.connectedAccountId; //this line is working!
        // Error:(35, 22) TS2339: Property 'connectedAccountReducer'
        // does not exist on type 'AppState'.
      });
```

**Why typescript throw those errors? How can I fix it?**

Comment: Try this `state['connectedAccountReducer'].connectedAccountId`

Comment: Okay its working so big and many thanks for that. I would like to know why I need to add ['connectedAccountReducer'] and how can we not use strings to get a type safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boostrap:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  AccountService,ConnectedAccountService,
  provideStore({connectedAccountReducer})
]);
```

Changed to:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      AccountService,ConnectedAccountService,
      provideStore(connectedAccountReducer) //{} removed.
    ]);
```

Incase you are using {} inside the provide store, use @Max solution that works great:
`state['reducer function name'].state property`